# How to find whether byte read is japanese or english?

Tags: c++, unicode, ascii, multibyte, multibyte-functions

I have an array which contains Japanese and ascii characters.
I am trying to find whether characters read is English character or Japanese characters.

in order to solve this i followed as

1. read first byte , if multicharcterswidth is not equal to one, move pointer to next byte
   now display whole two byte together and display that Japanese character has been read.
2. if multicharcterswidth is equal to one, display the byte. and show message english has been read.

above algo work fine but fails in case of halfwidth form of Japanese eg.ｼ,ｧ etc. as it is only one byte.
How can i find out whether characters are Japanese or English?

**Note:**What i tried
I read from web that first byte will tell whether it is japanese or not which i have covered in step 1 of my algo. But It won't work for half width.

EDIT:
The problem i was solving i include control characters 0X80 at start and end of my characters to identify the string of characters.
i wrote following to identify the end of control character.

cntlchar.....(my characters , can be japnese).....cntlchar

```
if ((buf[*p+1] & 0X80) && (mbMBCS_charWidth(&buf[*p]) == 1))
  // end of control characters reached
else
  // *p++
```

it worked fine when for english but didn't work for japanese half width.

How can i handle this?

Comment: Latin character, there are no English characters unless you mean ancient English.

Comment: What character sets and encoding are you using? The same for both english and japanese, or two different character sets?

Comment: The character set in use should tell you what 'byte' corresponds to what character. Whether the *displayed* character 'is' Japanese or English is irrelevant, and you should make that distinction for each value.

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: You need to explain why you need to distinguish between "Japanese" and "English" characters, including what you're going to do differently as a result. People tend to assume that Unicode solves everything and so if you're concerned about details like this than you musy be doing something wrong. That may be the case in your program, but sometimes details like these are important. It's not possible to give a good answer about what you should do without knowing what you're trying accomplish.

Comment: @Ross please see my EDIT section

Comment: The example code you added doesn't actually detect control characters on any character set I can think of. If you're using `0x80` as mask bit to mark character values, that won't work with anything but 7-bit ASCII. If you intend to use the character value `0x80` as a sentinel that you insert into strings than your code isn't detecting the sentinel correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data must be using [Windows Codepage 932](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305152.aspx). That is a *guess*, but examining the codepoints shows what you are describing.

The codepage shows that characters in the range `00` to `7F` are "English" (a better description is "7-bit ASCII"), the characters in the ranges `81` to `9F` and `E0` to `FF` are the first byte of a multibyte code, and everything between `A1` and `DF` are half-width Kana characters.

Answer (score 0):

For individual bytes this is impractical to impossible. For larger sets of data you could do statistical analysis on the bytes and see if it matches known English or Japanese patterns. For example, vowels are very common in English text but different Japanese letters would have similar frequency patterns.

Things get more complicated than testing bits if your data includes accented characters.

If you're dealing with Shift-JIS data and Windows-1252 encoded text, ideally you just remap it to UTF-8. There's no standard way to identify text encoding within a text file, although things like MIME can help if added on externally as metadata.